# Boss says that I'm pretty a good worker but not as good as XXX

Tags: performance

I had a casual conversation with my boss while running errand with him today.  When the discussion came to my work he said that I'm pretty good but not as good of a worker as ___ who was a previous employee that left.  Should I be worried and is he insinuating that I need to step it up?

Comment: Are you relatively new?  And is this a very small company?  If so, it would be natural to refer to ____ that way if ____ had been an employee for a while (compared to you), or perhaps one of the early/original employees.  Your value will go up with time, especially given that your boss already has a favorable impression of you.

Comment: Did he told you what to make better ? as it can be a bad way to talk to you about what to ameliorate.

Comment: You should have told him "Oh really? Well you're not as good as my old boss too!" just to make him feel what you felt like.

Comment: Well obviously you just need to be more hard core.

Comment: Very few workplace-related things are as good as XXX.

Answer (score 14):

You should be worried, but not for the reason you think.

Describing your performance in comparison to another individual is an incredibly unprofessional thing for your boss to do.  Either he is very naive as a manager, or he is being a jerk on purpose.  Either way, working for him is likely going to be rather unpleasant.

Answer (score 2):

No need to worry. "Pretty good worker" is the most important thing. And if you are the second best of ten workers, but not as good as the best, your job is safe. Especially if the best worker doesn't work there anymore :-)

Comment: well the thing is he only had like 3-4 employee not 10 if I was 9 out of 10 then yes I would agree